# Obter valor de elemento após conteúdo do AJAX ser carregado

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Bom, estou com algumas dúvidas em relação a utização do Ajax. Estou tentando obter um valor de um determinado elemento `<tr>`. Para isso coloquei um atributo `data-` na `<tr>` que é gerado dinamicamente por PHP, porém sempre tenho o retorno de *undefined*.

Minha chamada AJAX:

```
    $("#consulta").click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/consulta.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#conteudoConsulta").html(data);
                $("#modalConsulta").modal("show");
            }
        });     
    });
```

Forma que estou usando para obter o valor:

```
    $("body").on("click", "tr", function () {
        $("tr").addClass("select");
        var id = $(this);
        alert(id.closest('tr').find('td').data('cod'));
    });
```

Como poderia ser feito nessa situação?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o `data-cod` está na `tr`, então você deveria pegar o valor com:

HTML:

```
<tr data-cod="algum valor">
```

JS:

```
$("body").on("click", "tr", function () {
   $("tr").addClass("select");
   var id = $(this);  // elemento clicado
   alert(id.data('cod')); // exibe o data-cod do elemento
});
```

Comment: Valeu!! Verifiquei o código depois e notei que foi falta de atenção minha. Aproveitando o tópico... Existe uma forma "melhor" de fazer essa operação?

Comment: Pelo simplicidade acho que essa é a melhor forma mesmo.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu, pode marca-la como certa. Abs!